# More then one constant buffer containing simple data, DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I try to be short - I'm playing with directx 11 2D right now and creating fucntions drawing geometrical primitives like rectangles, lines, text output, circles including different overloads like filled with color and so on - I have 1 constant buffer that contained world and projection matrices, 1 color XMFLOAT4 for a primitive color and a FLOAT variable for transparency. Worked pretty well until I created a circle with 2 colors - of the border and of the filing. My first thought was to create a second constant buffer, add there second color and remove transparency index, since I dont plan it for a filled circle. But it adds more constant buffers rotation and updating, I mean before I had only 1 main constant buffer for all shaders, but now I need to vary them every single primitive call. Additionaly I read at nvidia that increasing constant buffers amount affects perfomance, but my knowledge are not enough to come to a good descision - should I have all-purpose constant buffer for all the primitives (matrices, both colors, transparency, anything else that is added up later) and just update it like before and is it a good move, or I need to keep separate buffers with differed data for separate shaders? I saw examples of shaders where , for example, matrices constant buffers and lights constant buffers were separated, that why I feel a bit confused. To sum all up: is a big constant buffer with all expected data better then some separated ones, being used evey swap call? Thank you, tho it was not really short :)

Comment: This question is merely unreadable (at least add some paragraphs to improve). Also you should give some concise code samples of what you're actually trying to do/achieve.

Comment: yeah, right point, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Back in Direct3D 9, there was a single block of shader constants. Typically if you updated any part of the block, all the data would have to be resent to the GPU.

For Direct3D 10, the concept of the Constant Buffer was created to address this problem. The advice was to use multiple constant buffers and organize them by 'frequency of update'. See the venerable presentation [Windows to Reality: Getting the Most out of Direct3D 10 Graphics in Your Games](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/4/a04deeb2-d7e2-42a5-984a-9ea5c92bfeb2/Windows%20to%20Reality%20-%20Getting%20the%20Most%20out%20of%20Direct3D%2010%20Graphics%20in%20your%20Games.zip). Much of the initial performance problems early Direct3D 10 games had was trying to just use one big constant buffer.

This advice still applies to Direct3D 11. With Windows 8 or later, the driver may or may not implement the optional feature "Constant Buffer offsetting" and "Constant Buffer partial updates".

Comment: awsome link, gives a lot of useful information, including thread point, thanks a lot, reading through right now:)